# I need help with the documents relating to my application to become a Dutch Citizen

Tags: citizenship

I qualify by law according to [this](http://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/Pages/by-birth-or-acknowledgement.aspx) statement on the website of the Dutch Immigration and Naturalisation Service:

> **Were you born before 1 January 1985?**
>
>   You are a Dutch citizen by law if your father was a Dutch citizen at the time of your birth. It does not matter whether you were born in the Netherlands or abroad.

But the problem is tracking down the documentation from Holland and South Africa. I presently live in South Africa. Are there any businesses or organizations that can assist?

Comment: Please add to your question where that statement comes from

Comment: @JanDoggen I think it's from [here](https://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/pages/by-birth-or-acknowledgement.aspx).

Comment: You should be aware that if you also hold another nationality you will most likely have lost your Dutch nationality through the ten-year rule, but the details of the rule have changed over the years, so it's not possible to say for sure without more information.

Comment: The statement comes from the document on the internet of the Dutch "Immigration and Naturalisation Service's website: (http://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/Pages/by-birth-or-acknowledgement.aspx)